# Line Breaks in Unix File

Tags: linux, file, awk, sed

I have a file with records delimited by |. There are a few line breaks where a part of the first line moves into the second line. If I calculate the number of | in a particular line, it should be consistent throughout. How do I identify which line has a line break as such and append two lines into one so as the number of '|' in each line is consistent throughout?

The file is something like below:

```
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Le
wis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis
|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borr
inson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000
```

whereas I want to calculate the number of '|' in each line.

In this case, each line should have 3 '|' each, but due to line breaks, that is not the case,

My final desired output is

```
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Lewis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borrinson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000
```

Comment: Please, post some example data and expected output.

Comment: the answer in the duplicate question works except for added space... so some modification is needed and I don't know if the change is trivial (not referring to field separator, but extra space)

Comment: Can't you use `sed` for replacing newline by an empty string? I mean, first you use ´awk´ to know the amount of `|` characters, and if it's smaller than 3, you remove the newline by an empty string.

Comment: @Dominique, yeah I implemented your idea in sed, simple enough as maximum split is across two lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One in awk:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }  # set separators
NR==1 { nf=NF }       # expect the field count to be correct on header record
NF<nf {               # if NF less than on header record
    while (NF<nf) {   # and while NF < less than on header record
        b=$0          # buffer too short record
        getline       # read next record
        $0 = b $0     # catenate buffer and fresh record
    }
} 1                   # output
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk foo
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Lewis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borrinson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000
```

No checks if record grows too long.

Answer (score 0):

Given that at max the split is across two lines as stated by OP in question, `sed` can be used for an easy solution

```
$ cat ip.txt 
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Le
wis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis
|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borr
inson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000

$ sed '/.*|.*|.*|/! {N; s/\n//}' ip.txt 
DeptID|EmpFName|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Lewis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borrinson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000
```

- `/.*|.*|.*|/!` if line doesn't contain three `|`

  - `{N; s/\n//}` get next line and remove first `\n`

Use grouping and quantifier to specify a number instead

```
sed '/\(.*|\)\{3\}/! {N; s/\n//}' ip.txt
```

with extended regex, `-E` or `-r`

```
sed -E '/(.*\|){3}/! {N; s/\n//}' ip.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the value 3 in a variable and use the variable in the above command.

I am trying to use the below, but it doesnt accept the variable value..


$ cat ip.txt
Deptme|EmpLName|Salary
Engg|Sam|Le
wis|1000
Engg|Smith|Davis|2000
HR|Denis
|Lillie|1500
HR|Danny|Borr
inson|3000
IT|David|Letterman|2000
IT|John|Newman|3000
$ var=$(sed 's/[^|]//g' ip.txt | awk '{ print length }' | head -1)
$ echo $var
2
$ sed '/\(.*|\)\{${var}\}/! {N; s/\n//}' ip.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: Invalid content of \{\}

Comment: use `sed "/\(.*|\)\{$var\}/! {N; s/\n//}" ip.txt`